# Make all fields in Java Immutable Nullable

Tags: java, immutability, nullable, immutables-library

```
@Immutable
@Modifiable
public interface Record {

    String id();

    String fName();

    String lName();

    String mName();
}
```

All the fields in `Record` can be `Nullable`. One way for me to make these fields `Nullable` is to add `@Nullable` annotation on top of each field. Like this:

```
@Nullable
String mName()
```

Is there a way for me to specify at the interface level(through some annotation) that all fields can be null?

Comment: You can make the type Optional

Answer (score 0):

I used the following config to disable null check in builder and with methods:

```
@Value.Style(
  validationMethod = Value.Style.ValidationMethod.NONE,
)
```

The following quote is the the ValidationMethod.NONE javadoc description:

> Disables null and mandatory attribute checks. Any missing primitives will be initialized to their zero-based values: false, 0, '\0'. Object references will be nulls. Any optional, default and collection attributes will be initialized with their appropriate default values regardless of this validation setting.